# separating bundles for dev from the ones you need in production

Tags: symfony

Why is there no distinction of dev and prod in autoload.php as in AppKernel.php?

I could check the environment, of course, but I am wondering if there is a reason for that.

B/c many bundles are useful for development, for example the admin interface needs a lot of bundles (I guess...). But I don't want to load those during production!

**autoload.php:**

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
    'Monolog'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
    'Assetic'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
    'Metadata'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
));
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    'Twig_Extensions_' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig-extensions/lib',
    'Twig_'            => __DIR__.'/../vendor/twig/lib',
));
```

**AppKernel.php:**

```
public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the autoloader is a standalone library. You could use it in a totally different project not related to Symfony2 as it is totally not coupled. As it is not coupled, it has to be env agnostic.

Second, the autoloader does not have the same algorithm as symfony1 and does not cache where the file are located. It's made on the fly, and you'll got tons of other performances issues before this one ;)

Comment: That's a good point! I am wondering about how to use certain components like the autoloader for example. what would you suggest is a good way to tackle that. the doc is only on standard usage of the as-is distribution. do I have to inspect the code and its documentation?

Comment: The documentation of the framework is pretty extensive, even if the documentation of components lacks. Then, you have the Symfony2 google group and the code as sources of knowledge.